# How to use Multiprocessing Queue with Lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

The posted code starts two async **Processes**. The first `publisher` **Process** publishes data to the `Queue`, the second `subscriber` **Process** reads the data from the `Queue` and logs it to console.

To make sure the Queue is not accessed at the same time, before getting the data from the `Queue`, the `subscribe` function first executes `lock.acquire()`, then gets the data with `data = q.get()` and finally releases the lock with the `lock.release()` statement.

The same locking-releasing sequence is used in `publish` function. But I had to comment two lines since acquiring the `lock` in `publish` 
function brings the script to halt. Why?

```
import multiprocessing, time, uuid, logging

log = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def publish(q):
    for i in range(20):
        data = str(uuid.uuid4())
        # lock.acquire()
        q.put(data)
        # lock.release()
        log.info('published: %s to queue: %s' % (data, q))
        time.sleep(0.2)

def subscribe(q):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        data = q.get()
        lock.release()
        log.info('.......got: %s to queue: %s' % (data, q))
        time.sleep(0.1)

publisher = multiprocessing.Process(target=publish, args=(queue,))
publisher.start()

subscriber = multiprocessing.Process(target=subscribe, args=(queue,))
subscriber.start()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `multiprocessing` *Queues* are thread and process safe.

And they support internal `block`ing mechanism (see the signatures of `get`/`put` methods).
You don't need a `lock` in your case.

```
import multiprocessing, time, uuid, logging

log = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

def publish(q):
    for i in range(20):
        data = str(uuid.uuid4())
        q.put(data)
        log.info('published: %s to queue: %s' % (data, q))
        time.sleep(0.2)
    q.put(None)

def subscribe(q):
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None:
            log.info('....... end of queue consumption')
            break
        log.info('.......got: %s to queue: %s' % (data, q))
        time.sleep(0.1)

publisher = multiprocessing.Process(target=publish, args=(queue,))
publisher.start()

subscriber = multiprocessing.Process(target=subscribe, args=(queue,))
subscriber.start()

publisher.join()
subscriber.join()
```

Sample output:

```
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-1] published: eff77f27-e13e-4d55-9f34-4ea5fc464fc8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: eff77f27-e13e-4d55-9f34-4ea5fc464fc8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 264fcf94-9195-4145-b0a1-5ddd787bee1f to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 264fcf94-9195-4145-b0a1-5ddd787bee1f to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 2e040d60-5fd4-45c9-98e6-f0032e13dae8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 2e040d60-5fd4-45c9-98e6-f0032e13dae8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: afe406ea-20cc-41b3-9cf5-c1dbea11580d to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: afe406ea-20cc-41b3-9cf5-c1dbea11580d to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: e14a6c04-e2fe-4394-a189-5c57c5a98bc8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: e14a6c04-e2fe-4394-a189-5c57c5a98bc8 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: fb90ba87-8090-4ec6-9ac1-85bcaa2bb3f6 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: fb90ba87-8090-4ec6-9ac1-85bcaa2bb3f6 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 85ab36ee-36f3-4c67-8260-7c41ea82a5d5 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 85ab36ee-36f3-4c67-8260-7c41ea82a5d5 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: d4dce917-9b5c-470a-9063-bfb0221da55f to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: d4dce917-9b5c-470a-9063-bfb0221da55f to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 1e1e2f02-932d-418d-b603-8c90f4699423 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 1e1e2f02-932d-418d-b603-8c90f4699423 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 0b80f1df-c803-4c00-be4d-fad39213829b to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 0b80f1df-c803-4c00-be4d-fad39213829b to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: f6afef2a-42f8-4330-b995-26ee41f833a5 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: f6afef2a-42f8-4330-b995-26ee41f833a5 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: abd85275-dc9f-478c-8528-23217db79631 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: abd85275-dc9f-478c-8528-23217db79631 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: c4fad226-8c83-4e52-beae-1cb9a825d370 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: c4fad226-8c83-4e52-beae-1cb9a825d370 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: ca16fd7d-ff51-4019-970c-f55c2b3c0db2 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: ca16fd7d-ff51-4019-970c-f55c2b3c0db2 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: eca614df-89da-47d0-a8a5-90b56fadb922 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: eca614df-89da-47d0-a8a5-90b56fadb922 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 046903d7-0fd8-4af0-ac49-a22efdc9c029 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 046903d7-0fd8-4af0-ac49-a22efdc9c029 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 7904d15a-7b04-4968-a52c-cfd8d822b921 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 7904d15a-7b04-4968-a52c-cfd8d822b921 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 8543b520-9a7e-4e22-afb3-a4880d910482 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 8543b520-9a7e-4e22-afb3-a4880d910482 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: b4e98f5e-ce63-4f11-a6f7-b7d36020deb0 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: b4e98f5e-ce63-4f11-a6f7-b7d36020deb0 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] published: 4a5eb231-4ccf-41e1-a0d6-ca41a50a6fd6 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-2] .......got: 4a5eb231-4ccf-41e1-a0d6-ca41a50a6fd6 to queue: <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x103528780>
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-2] ....... end of queue consumption
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: looks multiprocessing logging is also thread and process safe?

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#thread-safety